# Max number per row with ngfor

Tags: css, angular, html-table, repeat

Is it possible to create new row in 'td' after ngFor reaches 10 image repeats, now pics are shown all in one td and shrinking as it gets more and more?

```
<td *ngFor="let row of pics">
      <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" [checked]="row.checked" value="{{row.url}}" (change)="addpic($event.target.checked, row.id)"></label>
       </div>                                 
       <img src="{{picroute}}{{row.img}}>
</td>
```

Comment: You should create array of array, first dimension for "row", second for "item"

Comment: try to play with the index of your for loop *ngFor="let row of pics; let i = index", having the index will allow you to know when to add the new row

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let page of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].slice(0,pics/10)">
   <td *ngFor="let row of pics.slice(page*10,(page+1)*10">
      <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" [checked]="row.checked" 
                     value="{{row.url}}" (change)="addpic($event.target.checked, row.id)">
          </label>
       </div>                                 
       <img src="{{picroute}}{{row.img}}>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think flex-box could be more useful, you can control the shrink ratio if you need, the most important, only an one dimension array is needed.

Comment: Without table, it’s easier to control styles

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in arrange(pics, 10)">
        <td ng-repeat="pic in row">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                        [checked]="row.checked" 
                        value="{{row.url}}" 
                        (change)="addpic($event.target.checked, row.id)">
                </label>
            </div>                                 
            <img src="{{pic}}"
        </td>
    </tr>
</td>

arrange(pics, numberPerRow) {
    var arrangedArray = [];
    while (pics.length > numberPerRow) {
        arrangedArray.push(arrangedArray.splice(0, numberPerRow));
    }
    arrangedArray.push(pics);
    return arrangedArray;
}
```

This is a somewhat elegant solution imo, just replace variables accordingly.